# How to list all pages in Google search results?

Tags: wordpress, seo, http-status-code-301

My website was recently hacked and Google mentioned "This site may be hacked" so I removed the entire wordpress website and changed server. I installed a new wordpress website however, Google is still crawling the old pages. It runs into 20+ Google pages meaning there's over 200 links generated by the hack.

Now, I would like to do a 301 Redirect to all this links using htaccess so Google cache faster and remove these links.

How do I list all this links displayed in the searched result? or is there a better way to do? Yes, I have asked Google for Review but they said it will take several weeks :(

Comment: You are best returning a 404 https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/docs/clean_site

Answer (score -1):

You can see all youre indexed pages by writing this in Google search

- site:example.com

Just write youre domain name instead of example.com